# Installing rabbitmq-server on RHEL

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, redhat, rhel

When trying to install rabbitmq-server on RHEL:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-1XX ~]$ sudo rpm -i rabbitmq-server-3.3.5-1.noarch.rpm 
  error: Failed dependencies:
     erlang >= R13B-03 is needed by rabbitmq-server-3.3.5-1.noarch

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-1XX ~]$ rpm -i rabbitmq-server-3.3.5-1.noarch.rpm 
  error: Failed dependencies:
    erlang >= R13B-03 is needed by rabbitmq-server-3.3.5-1.noarch
```

I'm unsure why trying to rpm install isn't recognizing my erlang install since running `$ erl`gives:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-1XX ~]$ which erl
  /usr/local/bin/erl
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-1XX ~]$ sudo which erl
  /bin/erl
```

Comment: Which version of Erlang do you have installed? You can find out by running: erl --version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to ensure that an up-to-date version of Erlang is installed. It is available in the EPEL repository.

You can install it by performing the following:

`wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-erlang.repo http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/peter/erlang/epel-erlang.repo`

`yum install erlang`

Following the above setup of Erlang, you can then proceed to install RabbitMQ as follows:

```
rpm --import http://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc
  yum install rabbitmq-server-3.3.5-1.noarch.rpm
```

You can find more info in their [setup guide](http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html)

Comment: Similar one.. but I do not have option for yum.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157859/rabbitmq-server-installation-centos-erlang-error  help or suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

You need to install erlang via RPM for it to recognise the dependency.

The erlang RPMs are available in the EPEL repository:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html