# Installing rabbitmq on centos7

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to install rabbotmq on centos7.
Following the official instructions, I ran:

```
sudo yum install rabbitmq-server-3.5.1-1.noarch.rpm
```

and I get this error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Examining rabbitmq-server-3.5.1-1.noarch.rpm: rabbitmq-server-3.5.1-1.noarch
Marking rabbitmq-server-3.5.1-1.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rabbitmq-server.noarch 0:3.5.1-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: erlang >= R13B-03 for package: rabbitmq-server-3.5.1-1.noarch
http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/peter/erlang/epel-7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirrors.hoobly.com
 * extras: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * updates: mirror.pac-12.org
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: rabbitmq-server-3.5.1-1.noarch (/rabbitmq-server-3.5.1-1.noarch)
           Requires: erlang >= R13B-03
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

then I tried installing erlang with the instructions from:
[Installing rabbitmq-server on RHEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855331/installing-rabbitmq-server-on-rhel)

It seemed to have been installed, but my rabbitmq installation still fails with the same message.
Any ideas how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something that I've fought with, and found that the best solution is to install Erlang and RabbitMQ from standalone RPMs outside of yum; see [Install Erlang](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html) in RMQ's documentation. Specifically, the stripped-down Erlang install provided by RabbitMQ (see [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/erlang/)) should install easily, then allow you to install RMQ from an RPM downloaded from the RabbitMQ site. If that package doesn't work, then try the Erlang distributions from [Erlang Solutions](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html).

Comment: YES. Thanks. I had to install their version of erlang.

Answer (score 8):

Following the instruction lead me to error: `No package rabbitmq-server-3.6.1-1.noarch.rpm available.`

Then I simply tried: `yum install rabbitmq-server`, it works for me.

Or checkout this one: [Rabbitmq at Digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-rabbitmq) - I used to config web monitoring on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ansible playbook i used to install rabbitmq on CentOS 7.

```
- name: install epel-release
  yum: name=epel-release state=latest
  tags: erlang

- name: install erlang from EPEL
  yum: name=erlang state=latest
  tags: erlang

- name: install new rabbitmq
  yum: name=https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.5.6/rabbitmq-server-3.5.6-1.noarch.rpm state=present
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to install Earlang first, this has worked for me :

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/rabbitmq/erlang/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum makecache
sudo yum install erlang -y
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
sudo yum install rabbitmq-server -y
rpm -qi rabbitmq-server
systemctl start rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl enable rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl status rabbitmq-server
```