# How to install Install rabbitmq server on centos7

Tags: rabbitmq, centos7, rabbitmq-exchange

I tried to follow this link on stackoverflow [install rabbitmq-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855331/installing-rabbitmq-server-on-rhel) but it is not working. Getting error No package rabbitmq-server-3.3.4-1.noarch.rpm available.

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-erlang.repo http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/peter/erlang/epel-erlang.repo
yum install erlang

rpm --import http://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc
  yum install rabbitmq-server-3.3.5-1.noarch.rpm
```

**Getting error**

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install rabbitmq-server-3.3.4-1.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/peter/erlang/epel-7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.excellmedia.net
 * epel: epel.mirror.net.in
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net
No package rabbitmq-server-3.3.4-1.noarch.rpm available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Did you download this file http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.5.4/rabbitmq-server-3.5.4-1.noarch.rpm ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either of below two commands

## yum localinstall rabbitmq-server-3.3.4-1.noarch.rpm

or

## rpm -Uvh rabbitmq-server-3.3.4-1.noarch.rpm

where -U to update if package is already installed, 
       -v for verbose output, 
       -h to print hash output