# erlang is no longer supported by Red Hat Enterprise Linux?

Tags: erlang, rhel

I'm trying installing Erlang on my REHL7.2, but unfortunately I failed. I tried two approaches

1. First I tried downloading a RPM package from official site of erlang (in fact the rpm package is for CentOS, but there's no RPM package for RHEL anyway), but

> error: Failed dependencies:
>
> libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by esl-erlang-19.0-1.x86_64
>
> libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0(WXU_2.8)(64bit) is needed by esl-erlang-19.0-1.x86_64

2. Then I tried

> $ wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
>
> $ rpm -Uvh erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm

But it failed too because

> No package erlang available.
>
> Error: Nothing to do

I wonder whether Erlang is no longer supported by RHEL? Otherwise how can I install Erlang on my RHEL7.2?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855331/installing-rabbitmq-server-on-rhel) or try [installing from source](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/HOWTO/INSTALL.md).

Comment: libwx_baseu-2.8.so: is the wxWidget library, not included in the erlang distribution. You should intall it before.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will try.....maybe tomorrow (I'm really busy right now T T )

Comment: FYI use https://github.com/kerl/kerl to compile and install/activate instead, as instructed on https://www.erlang.org/downloads

Comment: @Nathaniel Thanks for your edit. Well I tried install from source and 'kerl', both failed. I have already reported on Github, hope those forks will pay attention.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50177105/272735 for details how to install Erlang from Erlang Solutions repository in RHEL7.5.

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution to install the [Erlang Solutions](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html) package is install the epel repository:

```
yum install epel-release
```

Then

```
    wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
    rpm -Uvh erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
    sudo yum install erlang
```

The epel repo contains the `libwx_*` libraries required.

Comment: In my case I had to enable `epel` repo first.

Comment: @xji How do you enable it ?

Answer (score 1):

As instructed here:

[enter link description here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.3.0/tutorials/installation/Installing-Erlang/)

Run the following commands (note: the commands on the above link use R15B01, but in the following commands, I changed it to the last release of Erlang (R15B03) It will take a while to finish with the installation. Run commands line by line

```
sudo yum install gcc glibc-devel make ncurses-devel openssl-devel autoconf

wget http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_R15B03.tar.gz

tar zxvf otp_src_R15B03.tar.gz

cd otp_src_R15B03

./configure && make && sudo make install
```

After everything is done, you will be still at otp_src_R15B03 where Erlang is installed. Type erl and Enter, then, it should run and open Erlang prompt. I tried running Erlang from my home directory and from the root by just typing erl and it worked too. This way, Erlang is working good for me. To quit Erlang press CTRL + g  then q and Enter

There is another way to install and useful info on this link:

[enter link description here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.0/setup/installing/source/erlang/#installing-on-rhel-centos)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out! I found two solutions.

The first solution which is also the easiest way is to install a zero dependency version of `erlang`, please refer to my another [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652034/rabbitmq-rpm-installation-failed-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-2-even-with-erla/38652410#38652410). But I only tried this way after installing `erlang` from source, so if you failed this way, just try the following soltuion.

The other one is to build `erlang` from source (or by `kerl` which is essentially the same thing).

1. Install necessary dependencies:`$sudo yum install ncurses-devel openssl-devel *openjdk-devel unixODBC unixODBC-devel`
2. Download source code of `erlang`, unzip it and `cd` into the direcotry
3. `sudo ./configure` `sudo make` `sudo make install`

Please refer to [this](http://imperialwicket.com/aws-install-erlang-otp-on-amazon-linux/) article.

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me.

```
 wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
 rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

 sudo yum install erlang erlang-nox
```