# RabbitMQ RPM installation failed on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2 (even with erlang installed)

Tags: installation, erlang, rabbitmq, rhel7

In the homepage of `RabbitMQ` it says

1. First install `erlang`
2. Then install `RabbitMQ` by

   `rpm --import https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-release-signing-key.asc`

   `yum install rabbitmq-server-3.6.3-1.noarch.rpm`

I installed `erlang` but when install RabbitMQ it failed, the error says

```
Requires: erlang>=R16B-03
```

But I have already installed `erlang 19.0`, what's the problem? Someone in other article suggested RabbitMQ doesn't support `erlang 19.0` right now, then what should I do? I have already installed `erlang 19.0` and tried installing `erlang 18.3` without deleting `erlang 19.0`, because I don't know how to uninstall `erlang` :( , it still fails (but `$erl` shows the version is `18.3`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ will support `Erlang 19.0` starting from the version `3.6.4` (currently in [RC1](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/rabbitmq_v3_6_4_rc1)).

I suggest to use the zero dependency Erlang/OTP 18.3.4 package here:

```
https://github.com/rabbitmq/erlang-rpm/releases/tag/v1.3.0
```

install it in this way:

```
wget https://github.com/rabbitmq/erlang-rpm/releases/download/v1.3.0/erlang-18.3.4-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm 
rpm -i erlang-18.3.4-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

To remove your current erlang installation try using:

```
sudo yum remove erlang*
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You must be an expert on 'erlang' because you know the zero dependency version. Unfortunately I didn't know that version, so in fact I installed 'erlang' from source which was rather a struggle. Anyway, your commands work! (I still had to 'yum install socat' which is needed by 'RabbitMQ') Thank you very much!